# Why did Danny Rand break the wall?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders

Being a long known fact in the storyline, why did Danny Rand break the wall that guarded the long hidden elements from the Hand?

> In the fight with Elektra, he should know that fight near the wall could accidentally break it.

But knowing that he uses the iron fist and breaks it at some point.

Why?

Comment: I really just want to say "because the script told him to." The plot really was *that* thin :/

Comment: Elektra tricks him into it - she goads him by pretending to try to recruit him, and that gets him, the boy with the short temper, frustrated enough that he will fight her, and she outclasses him, making him angrier until he resorts to his one cheat - the iron fist, which she then, through choreograpy, manipulates to miss her and hit the wall

Comment: He didn't break the wall knowingly. He was tricked into doing it.

Comment: @GhotiandChips seems like a potential answer

Comment: Did anyone else think this was a GoT question from the title?

Comment: Because he's the worst Ironfirst ever.  ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, I was pretty disappointed with the series

Comment: @OrangeDog too much GOT questions here

Comment: @userLTK who else could be iron fist except Danny Rand? or you meant the actor is worst?

Comment: @Vishwa I was just pulling a quote from the series.   I didn't mean anything beyond just pulling the quote cause I thought, him accidentally opening the lock was proof that he was a bad iron first.   But, I mostly just pulled the quote for fun.   There are theories out there that suggest that line pays tribute to the bad reviews of the series.    Netflix very well could have meant that but I just thought it was a funny line.   http://68.media.tumblr.com/f8e9ac74c8ce8a5d210e0234071fb722/tumblr_on8af1tk4H1vo3326o6_250.gif

Comment: @userLTK yeah, it was quite sarcastic actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### He's tricked and manipulated into it by Elektra.

She tells him that she killed the monks of K'un-Lun and pretending to try to bring him into the Hand all to get him angry.

She taunts him and beats him in a fight until he turns to the one weapon he has that he thinks that will beat her....the one weapon that **he knows she wants** and **he does it anyway** even after *telling* her that he wouldn't give it to her.

Danny Rand has shown himself to be childish, impetuous and unable to control his emotions and Elekta plays him like a fiddle.

When he finally commits she uses footwork, positioning and martial arts moves to trap the *iron fist* and turn it to the target she wants.

[image]

Comment: He was trained to avoid situations like in his whole life. why couldn't he prevent it from happening? His whole training and purpose is to prevent events like this. Is this means he fails big time as an iron fist?

Comment: He ignores his training because he can't control his emotions. Tha's the point. ...and yes, I'd call it a failure. He doesn't protect K'un-Lun or destroy the Hand...those were his two primary missions and he fails at both.

Comment: His training is incomplete at this point.  He's still young and impetuous, he got angry and made a mistake that Elektra was goading him into.